# How to loop through all the files in a directory and print all the file names, like the command tree

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory, for

How can I mimic the `tree` command and iterate through all the files and subdirectories of a directory and echo all the file names?

I thought that a subdirectory within a directory is still counted as a directory, so I did:

```
for FILE in *; do
if [ -d $FILE ]
then echo "$FILE is a directory";
else echo "$FILE is a file"
fi
done
```

How can I make this recursive and loop inside the subdirectories and iterate through all the files and print their file name + path?

This is a shell script using bash. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you didn't use this exact code, because `'$FILE'` evaluates to the string `$FILE` and not to the file name. (and assuming you have nothing that is called `$FILE` in your directory, this nonexistent filesystem entry is of course always *not a directory*)

Comment: By the way, the inference "is not a directory, so must be file" is wrong; can be a symlink, a device node, a socket or a named pipe, too.

Comment: Edited the post, thanks for the clarification. Also, would you know the answer to the remaining question? Do I just put another `for` loop inside the original loop?

Comment: With regards to the "is not a directory, so must be file" is wrong, is that very important? I just need to list all the files that has lines inside of it. I assume that symlink, a device node, a socket or a named pipe does not have lines inside of it?

Comment: Symlinks might, depending on whether you think of the symlink itself as a file or of whatever it is the link is pointing to, but it doesn't matter. One of the main points of the Unix philosophy is that everything (and that actually includes directories) [is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

Comment: Tre `find` command print all the filenames (with their directory). You can filter (only files : `find -type f`). But if you want a definitive answer, you should edit your question and give us an exemple of the output you want. Printing filenames "like `tree`", can be complex because of all the graphic characters involved. Is it really what you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an equivalent to terdon's shell function implemented as a `find` command:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'for f; do
                      [ -d "$f" ] && is_dir="" || is_dir="not "
                      printf "\"%s\" is %sa directory\n" "$f" "$is_dir"
                    done' sh {} +
```

Or with find & perl (indenting two spaces per directory level and using NUL as the filename separator):

```
find . -print0 | \
  perl -0ne '$is_dir = -d $_ ? "" : "not ";
             $f = $_; $indent = ($f =~ s=/==g);
             printf "  " x $indent . "%s is %sa directory\n", $_, $is_dir'
```

Most of the perl one-liner is straight-forward and obvious, but one line might require some explanation:

```
$f = $_; $indent = ($f =~ s=/==g);
```

This copies the current input record (i.e. the filename, `$_`) into variable `$f`.  $f is then modified to remove all `/` characters while the count of changes is stored in variable `$indent`. `$f` isn't used again, it's just a throwaway variable to avoid changing `$_`.

The `$indent` variable is used with the repetition operator (`x` - similar to multiplication but for strings, see `man perlop`) to construct the printf format string.

---

To count the files and directories, with 3-digit wide numbering of each line:

```
$ find . -print0 | perl -0ne '
    if ( -d $_ ) {
      $is_dir = "";
      $dirs++
    } else {
      $is_dir = "not ";
      $files++
    };

    $f = $_; $indent = ($f =~ s=/==g);
    #printf "  " x $indent . "%s is %sa directory\n", $_, $is_dir;
    printf "%3i: " . "  " x $indent . "%s is %sa directory\n", $., $_, $is_dir;

    END {
      # simple method to determine singular or plural word forms
      # without using the Lingua::EN::Inflect module
      # (see https://metacpan.org/release/Lingua-EN-Inflect)
      my $d_word = ($dirs  != 1) ? "directories" : "directory";
      my $f_word = ($files != 1) ? "files" : "file";

      print "\n$dirs $d_word, $files $f_word\n";
    }'
```

The perl part of this one-liner has got to the point where it is no longer reasonable to edit on the command line, because dealing with absurdly long lines is a complete PITA - it's much easier to use a text editor.  It should be saved to a script file somewhere in your $PATH (e.g. `~/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin` - add to your PATH if it's not already there) with `#!/usr/bin/perl -0ne` as the first line and made executable with `chmod +x`.

Comment: it doesn't do the indentation like terdon's edited version....and it's too late at night for me to want to write shell code to do that. if anyone wants to take it from here, feel free.

Comment: Note that this, unlike mine, will not descend into symlinked directories. No idea if this is what the OP wants or not.

Comment: it would be easy with a simple perl one-liner to count the `/` characters to figure out the indentation level.  maybe tomorrow.

Comment: `find` has a `-L` option for following symlinks if that is required.

Comment: Hello, I tried both solutions and it worked. I was wondering if I wanted to add `wc -l` to count the lines per log file, where would I put it?

Comment: I tried this: 

`find . -print0 | \
                perl -0ne '$is_dir = -d $_ ? "" : "not ";
                                 $f = $_; $indent = ($f =~ s=/==g); $lines = $(wc -l)
                                 printf "  " x $lines $indent . "%s is %sa directory\n", $_, $is_dir'`

And it says missing operator before `wc` and `indent`

Comment: For the shell version, probably easiest to pipe it into `tee >(wc -l)`, that will send the output to both stdout and to `wc -l`.  For the perl version, easiest to add something like `END { print "lines: $.\n"}' to the bottom of the script (`$.` is perl's built-in line-counter variable).   It wouldn't be too hard to modify either version to keep count of files & directories separately, and print them after the main loop has finished, similarly to how tree does it.

Comment: perl is not shell. and what you tried wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to add `$.` to the perl before the indent such that `printf "  " x $. $indent . "%s is %sa directory\n", $_, $log_files'` because I want the line count per file to appear in a straight vertical line on the leftmost part. However it says  missing operator? Sorry for the follow-ups, I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: try something like: `printf "%3i: " . "  " x $indent . "%s is %sa directory\n", $., $_, $is_dir;`.  change the `%3i` to adjust the amount of padding for the line counter, or change to just `%i` if you don't want any padding.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interested in separating directories from everything else, you can do something like this, using a recursive function:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Do not expand globs to themselves if they don't match
shopt -s nullglob

list_files(){
  ## if a target has been passed as an argument, use that; if not,
  ## default to '.', the current directory.
  target=${1:-.}
  for i in "$target"/*; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
      list_files "$i"
    else
      echo "$i is not a directory"
    fi
  done
}

list_files "$@"
```

Given a directory structure like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── file
│   │   ├── subsubdir1
│   │   └── subsubdir2
│   └── subdir2
│       ├── file
│       ├── subsubdir1
│       └── subsubdir2
├── dir2
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── subsubdir1
│   │   └── subsubdir2
│   └── subdir2
│       ├── subsubdir1
│       └── subsubdir2
└── symlink -> 2.txt

15 directories, 6 files
```

The code above produces:

```
$ bar.sh
"./1.txt" is not a directory
"./2.txt" is not a directory
"./3.txt" is not a directory
"./dir1" is a directory
"./dir1/subdir1" is a directory
"./dir1/subdir1/file" is not a directory
"./dir1/subdir1/subsubdir1" is a directory
"./dir1/subdir1/subsubdir2" is a directory
"./dir1/subdir2" is a directory
"./dir1/subdir2/file" is not a directory
"./dir1/subdir2/subsubdir1" is a directory
"./dir1/subdir2/subsubdir2" is a directory
"./dir2" is a directory
"./dir2/subdir1" is a directory
"./dir2/subdir1/subsubdir1" is a directory
"./dir2/subdir1/subsubdir2" is a directory
"./dir2/subdir2" is a directory
"./dir2/subdir2/subsubdir1" is a directory
"./dir2/subdir2/subsubdir2" is a directory
"./symlink" is not a directory
```

You can also make it a little easier to read by adding an offset to indicate the depth in the directory tree, and by processing all directories first so as to have a more ordered output:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Do not expand globs to themselves if they don't match
shopt -s nullglob

list_files(){
  ## if a target has been passed as an argument, use that; if not,
  ## default to '.', the current directory.
  target=${1:-.}

  for i in "$target"/*; do
    offset=${2:-""}
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
      printf '%s"%s" is a directory\n' "$offset" "$i"
      for subdir in "$i"/*/; do
        new_offset="$offset   "
        list_files "$i" "$new_offset"
        new_offset=""
      done
    else
      printf '%s"%s" is not a directory\n' "$offset" "$i" 
    fi
  done
}

list_files "$@"
```

This will produce the following output on the example input above:

```
$ foo.sh 
"./1.txt" is not a directory
"./2.txt" is not a directory
"./3.txt" is not a directory
"./dir1" is a directory
   "./dir1/subdir1" is a directory
      "./dir1/subdir1/file" is not a directory
      "./dir1/subdir1/subsubdir1" is a directory
      "./dir1/subdir1/subsubdir2" is a directory
         "./dir1/subdir1/subsubdir2/file" is not a directory
   "./dir1/subdir2" is a directory
      "./dir1/subdir2/file" is not a directory
      "./dir1/subdir2/subsubdir1" is a directory
      "./dir1/subdir2/subsubdir2" is a directory
"./dir2" is a directory
   "./dir2/subdir1" is a directory
      "./dir2/subdir1/subsubdir1" is a directory
      "./dir2/subdir1/subsubdir2" is a directory
   "./dir2/subdir2" is a directory
      "./dir2/subdir2/subsubdir1" is a directory
      "./dir2/subdir2/subsubdir2" is a directory
"./symlink" is not a directory
```

Note that this approach will descend into symlinked directories. For example, if I add this:

```
$ ln -s dir2 dirsym
$ ls -ld dirsym
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 4 Apr  8 16:03 dirsym -> dir2
```

Then `dirsym` will be treated as a directory and its contents will be reported just like its target, `dir2`, effectively repeating the `dir2` output. I don't know if this is the desired behavior or not. If it isn't, use [caz's `find` approach instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742328/22222).

Answer (score 0):

```
(
  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 printf '%s is a file\0'
  find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 printf '%s is a directory\0'
) | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

I'm not sure if I consider this to be a good answer, was something of a "I wonder if I could..."

Produce a list of files and directories.

Print them with appropriate suffix.

Then sort the entire result so items appear in the right context.

Some extra fiddling needed to handle items with newline characters in their name.